# Testing timers in React HOC component

Tags: reactjs, intervals, jestjs

I am trying to test intervals in component, but it doesn't work.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

  export const withTimer = WrappedComponent =>enter code here {
    class WithTimer extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          elapsedTime: 0
        }
      }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.intervalId = setInterval(
        () =>
          this.setState(({ elapsedTime }) => ({
            elapsedTime: elapsedTime + 1
          })),
        1000
      );
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      const { elapsedTime } = this.state;
      if (elapsedTime >= 2) {
        run_function();
      }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          elapsedTime={this.state.elapsedTime}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  return WithTimer;
};
```

Test:

```
describe("<WithTimer />", () => {
  const InnerComponent = () => {
    return <div>hello</div>;
  };
  const Comp = withTimer(InnerComponent);

  it("updates correctly", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Comp />, {lifecycleExperimental: true });
    wrapper.update();
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(3123);
    jest.runAllTimers()
    wrapper.update();

    expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```

I tried few combinations, but *elapsedTime* doesn't update and the *run_function()* is not triggered. 
Interval function is mock correctly, but it was called zero times.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Define attribute `intervalId` in the constructor so it is reachable in the whole class.

```
class WithTimer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            elapsedTime: 0
        }
        this.intervalId = null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also I suggest you to improve your code checking if the `setInterval` is defined to avoid buggy behaviour on component mounting and unmounting.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(!this.intervalId) {
        this.intervalId = setInterval(
            () =>
                this.setState(({ elapsedTime }) => ({
                    elapsedTime: elapsedTime + 1
            })),
            1000
        );
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.intervalId = null;
}
```